# Hi, i want to install Blender so i downloaded windows64.msi version but my computer is not supporting the file

Tags: installation, versions

i want to install Blender so i downloaded windows64.msi version but my computer is not supporting the file. Can you suggest me which file should i install. I mention my computer specifications
WIndows-7
processor- Pentium(R) Dual Core- 3GHz 
System- 32bit Operating system

Comment: Uh... You can't use 64-Bit software on a 32-Bit operating system. [Blender 2.80](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/) is the last version that's available on 32-bit operating systems. Also (and although I'm still using it myself) Windows 7 is not going to be supported for very much longer.